# How to reference my Assembly to loaded assembly

Tags: c#

I want to implement modding support for my game and I decided to do it with C# modding so users can put dll-s in a mods folder and my game loads them. I did some googling and I found Assembly.LoadFrom(path) but my problem is that I want to specify the class in the other assembly what classes (namespaces) can it access (add my game namespace to it, remove system.io from it) and I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether I understand you correctly, but IMO it cannot be made or it would be just a dirty hack.

Basically accessibility is checked by both compiler and CLR(and just-in-time compiler) by marking your classes public/internal/private etc. They ensure that all language rules are not violated, so I don't see why you would need to specify it on your own.

If you want to make your classes accessible only for your assembly, just mark them `internal`.